# Using jQuery to check and clear forms with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm attempting to write a script that creates float labels without a ton of repeating HTML. The script pulls data defined in the input form adds, a wrapper and label and clears the form. This works well. The second part of the script hides/shows the label based on user input, and removes the user input if they type the "title", the value carried over to the tag.

Below is a JSFiddle and the section of code I am having trouble with.

http://jsfiddle.net/chdhmphry/pDAv9/

```
input.keyup(function(){

    ctn.addClass("active-filled");
    var userText2 = input.val();
    console.log(userText2);

    if(userText2 === ""){
        ctn.removeClass("active-filled");
    }

    input.blur(function(){

        if(userText2 === title){
            ctn.removeClass("active-filled");
        }

    });

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would not create the label through the DOM. I would hard-code it. It is an unnecessary action. Normally the label would be at the left for text inputs or just above.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kef5f/1/

Comment: @johanVandenRym I added the CSS for some context. Eventually the label will float somewhere, but I wanted to get the script down first.

Comment: @arunpjohny Awesome! Thank you! However, would you mind explaining why exactly yours work while mine breaks? Thanks again!